# How to create a build pipeline for a repo's wiki?

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, azure-pipelines

I want to run a markdown linter on our repo's wiki. But I can't seem to select the wiki as a repo from the "new build pipeline" drop down.

Has anyone done this, or know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Wiki and get the Wiki repo URL:

[image]

[image]

Create a Build pipeline and select "External Git" as the repo source:

[image]

Paste your Wiki repo URL:

[image]

Now you can run a markdown linter on the Wiki repo :)